# javascript extension error: Cannot perform modifications

Tags: paw-app

I'm building a [custom dynamicValue extension](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/extensions/create-dynamic-value) for paw. However i'm not able to set header in the `evaluate` method. See the sample code below:

```
evaluate(context) {
  const request = context.getCurrentRequest();
  request.setHeader('Content-Type', this.contentType); // <-- this gives warning
  return this.createSignable(request); // This returns a base64 string.
}
```

I get the warning saying `Javascript extension error: Cannot perform modifications` and the header is not set. ( when i comment out `request.setHeader` call, i get no warnings)
[image]
Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, you cannot use setters (set any value) in a dynamic value. In fact, the way Paw evaluates dynamic values is asynchronous and as multiple evaluations can take place simultaneously it would be impossible to record the modifications. For this reason, Paw is simply denying changes and no change is persisted during evaluation.

In the [documentation](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/reference/Request), it's specified that these methods (like `setHeaders`) is only available for importer extensions. Sorry for the inconvenience!

I think to achieve what you're trying to do, you would need two dynamic values one set in the `Authorization` header and one set in the `Content-Type` header.

Alternatively, in the future we're going to add request post-processors, so you'll be able to mutate the computed request ready to be sent to the server for additional modifications.

Comment: Thanks Micha! That's exactly what i did. created two dynamic value headers. Anyways thanks for this awesome tool. Looking forward to `request post-processor` feature.